# Неверно деобфусцировал код

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как-то раз, давным-давно я захотел минифицировать свой JS-код, но случайно зашёл на сайт, который помимо минификации ещё и обфусцирует его. Я это заметил не сразу, а лишь спустя, ибо торопился поскорее закончить работу. Теперь я решил этот код вручную деобфусцировать, но сломал при этом функционал. Суть в том, что при клике на инпут появлялось выпадающее меню, а если кликнуть где-то в другое место, то оно скрывалось. Я переписал этот код на читаемый, но при этом сломался тот самый функционал, отвечающий за закрытие выпадающего меню. Почему это произошло? Ведь я в точности переписал код.

Новый код:

```
$(() => {
    let dropdown = $('.passengers-main-dropdown');

    dropdown.on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).nextAll('.dropdown-box').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('body').on('click', function(e){
        let drop = $('.dropdown-box');
        console.log(`${dropdown.is(e.target)} + ${dropdown.has(e.target).length !== 0} + ${drop.has(e.target).length !== 0)}`)
        if(dropdown.is(e.target) && dropdown.has(e.target).length !== 0 && drop.has(e.target).length !== 0) {
            drop.removeClass('active');
            dropdown.removeClass('active');
        }
    })
});
```

Старый (обфусцированный) код:

```
$(function() {
    var t = $(".passengers-main-dropdown");
    t.on("click", function() {
        t.nextAll(".dropdown-box").toggleClass("active"), t.toggleClass("active")
    }), $("body").on("click", function(o) {
        var i = $(".dropdown-box");
        t.is(o.target) || 0 !== t.has(o.target).length || 0 !== $(i).has(o.target).length || (i.removeClass("active"), t.removeClass("active"))
    })
})
```

Проблема, скорее всего, в этой строке:
`t.is(o.target) || 0 !== t.has(o.target).length || 0 !== $(i).has(o.target).length || (i.removeClass("active"), t.removeClass("active"))`

У меня она переписана, как:

`if(dropdown.is(e.target) && dropdown.has(e.target).length !== 0 && drop.has(e.target).length !== 0) {
    drop.removeClass('active');
    dropdown.removeClass('active');
}`

Несмотря на то, что в обфусцированном варианте кода используется оператор `||`(или), переписанный код с этим оператором не работает вовсе. С оператором `&&`(и) выпадающий список работает, однако, почему-то не скрывается по клику вне. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, где я допустил ошибку.

Comment: ОМГ, а вы что, не храните исходный код?

Comment: @NickVolynkin на то время я ещё не умел делать бэкапы. Да и как-то не парился особо.

Comment: Обфусцированный код хранить вообще не надо, лол. Он должен быть в опубликованной релизной версии, но никак не в локальной версии для разработки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная строка кода:

```
t.is(o.target) || 0 !== t.has(o.target).length || 0 !== $(i).has(o.target).length || (i.removeClass("active"), t.removeClass("active"))
```

имеет вид:

```
a || b || c || d
```

> JavaScript вычисляет несколько `ИЛИ` слева направо. При этом, чтобы экономить ресурсы, используется так называемый [«короткий цикл вычисления»](https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Если выражение `a` вернет `true`, то вычислять выражения `b`, `c`, `d` не имеет смысла.
Очевидно, выражение `d` вычислится только тогда, когда выражения `a`, `b` и `c` вернут `false`.

```
if (a == false && b == false && c == false) {
  d
}
```

Преобразованный код для вашей задачи:

```
if (!dropdown.is(e.target) && dropdown.has(e.target).length === 0 && $(drop).has(e.target).length === 0) {
  drop.removeClass("active");
  dropdown.removeClass("active")
}
```

Comment: `.length` ты зря потерял...

Comment: @Qwertiy почему?

Comment: Потому что это jQuery. Там has возвращает набор элементов, который никогда не бывает ложным. А вот пустым бывает.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен. Исправил